# APDU Selecting specific file and reading binary data

Tags: c#, pcsc

I'm trying to read a very specific binary information from a Smart Card using PC/SC API in c#.

I Want to select a specific file

```
00 A4 02 0C 02 05 20
```

And read binary data

```
00 B0 00 00 8F
```

As far as I know the 5 bytes for reading binary data is in the following order:

```
Class, Instruction, Parameter 1, Parameter 2, Length
```

**My first question is in what order the select file array of 7 bytes is.**

```
Class,Instruction, Parameter 1, Parameter 2, ?,?,?
```

**My second question is what IsoCase and Protocol I should use for each command.**

Following case and protocol seems to work for reading binary data but it confuses me since I'm not using a SmartCard and not RFID.

```
var apdu = new CommandApdu(IsoCase.Case2Short,rfidReader.ActiveProtocol)
```

---

Using PCSC-sharp.dll from https://code.google.com/p/pcsc-sharp/:

```
using PCSC;
using PCSC.Iso7816;
```

Answer (score 2):

I overdid this and overlooked a very important detail. 
The file I was trying to open was a subfile and could not be opened until its parent is already opened.

It worked when I opened all files in the correct order before reading binary data.

I didn't even have to set protocols and IsoCases. Just did a transmit of the bytes.

```
ScardReader reader = new ScardReader();

reader.Transmit(bytesToSend, ref ResponseBuffer);
```

Comment: Do you still know what was in your bytesToSend array?